# Unity Mecanim Blend Issue on 180 Degree Turn

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a quadruped that I want to animate with mecanim in Unity. I have set up a root node for it, and the animation rotates/moves it correctly. I have 2 mecanim states - turning 180 degrees and forward walking. I set a transition between this 2 states. When the blending comes into the action and I want the animal to rotate 180 degrees and walk forward, at the end of the turn instead of continuing walking, it turns another 360 degrees and then does walking animation.
In the [attached video](https://youtu.be/oaQWTQ2GVro) you can see the described behaviour.
Any help on this is highly appreciated.